# Run django application without django.contrib.admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-admin-tools

I am trying to run my Django Application without Django admin panel because I don't need it right now but getting an exception value:

> Put 'django.contrib.admin' in your INSTALLED_APPS setting in order to
>   use the admin application.

Could I ran my application without `django.contrib.admin` ? Even if go my `localhost:8000` it is showing you need to add `django.contrib.admin` in your installed_apps?

Comment: Can you show your URLs file? I believe by default Django includes the admin urls now.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`django.contrib.admin` is simply a Django app.

Remove or comment  `django.contrib.admin` from `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py` file.

Also remove or comment `from django.contrib import admin` from `admin.py'`,`urls.py` and all the files having this import statement.

Remove `url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)` from `urlpatterns` in `urls.py`.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue.

I had `#url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),` in my `urls.py` which I just commented out.