# Skip django migrate default table

Tags: python, django

I use `django-admin startproject` to create a new project, then use `python manage.py migrate`.

I find there are some tables will create by default.
[image]

I want migrate my tables only when I run `python manage.py migrate`. Is it possible to skip the default?

Comment: You can apply migrations manually. See `manage.py migrate --help`. But don't expect your application to work properly until all migrations are applied.

Comment: Not sure if you can, but you can directly apply the migration to your app. `manage.py migrate {app_name}`

Answer (score 0):

By default, `INSTALLED_APPS` contains `django.contrib.admin` and `django.contrib.auth` apps (along with few other apps). These apps are part of Django. These apps are optional, and can be removed if you do not need functionality they provide (See: [Run django application without django.contrib.admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33420918/run-django-application-without-django-contrib-admin)).

[`python manage.py makemigrations`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-makemigrations) will create the migrations files for all the changes to models **in all the apps**.
And [`python manage.py migrate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/django-admin/#migrate) will apply previously computed migrations to the database.

When you have multiple apps, use `python manage.py makemigrations [app_name]`, and `python manage.py migrate [app_name]` to limit these operations to specific app.